# List of served files in apache

Tags: apache, file, request

I am doing some reverse engineering on a website.

We are using LAMP stack under CENTOS 5, without any commercial/open source framework (symfony, laravel, etc). Just plain PHP with an in-house framework.

I wonder if there is any way to know which files in the server have been used to produce a request.

For example, let's say I am requesting http://myserver.com/index.php.

Let's assume that 'index.php' calls other PHP scripts (e.g. to connect to the database and retrieve some info), it also includes a couple of other html files, etc

How can I get the list of those accessed files?

I already tried to enable the server-status directive in apache, and although it is working I can't get what I want (I also passed the 'refresh' parameter)

I also used lsof -c httpd, as suggested in other forums, but it is producing a very big output and I can't find what I'm looking for.

I also read the apache logs, but I am only getting the requests that the server handled.

Some other users suggested to add the PHP directives like 'self', but that means I need to know which files I need to modify to include that directive beforehand (which I don't) and which is precisely what I am trying to find out.

Is that actually possible to trace the internal activity of the server and get those file names and locations?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I tried this, but it looks like [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html) is the answer to my own question